# In Inheritance method the Child class not receiving the URL from the Parent class

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, selenium-chromedriver, testng

**This is Parent Class to run the ChromeDriver**.

```
 package logInCredit;
 
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 public class  LogInPage  {

 public WebDriver driver ;

 public void LogInCredit() {


 //Open ChromeDriver    
 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 System.out.println(driver);


 }

 }
```

**This Is Child Class which takes the url from Parent Class**

```
 package afterLogIn;


 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import logInCredit.LogInPage;


 public class NextLogIn extends LogInPage {


    @Test
    public void DashboardPage() {
    
    
    System.out.println("driver is " +driver);
    
    
    //Admin UserName Enter
    WebElement AdminUserName = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtUsername']"));
    AdminUserName.sendKeys("Admin");
    
    //Admin Password Enter
    WebElement AdminPassword = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtPassword']"));
    AdminPassword.sendKeys("admin123");
    
    //click Login
    WebElement LogInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnLogin']"));
    LogInButton.click();
    
    
    WebElement ClickAdmin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Admin']"));
    ClickAdmin.click();
    
    
    WebElement ClickPIM = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='PIM']"));
    ClickPIM.click();
}
    
}
```

**This is my testng.xml  file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="After Login Test">
   <classes>
      <class name="afterLogIn.NextLogIn"/>  
   </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**While running the program I get the Exception**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
driver is null
FAILED: DashboardPage
java.lang.NullPointerException
at afterLogIn.NextLogIn.DashboardPage(NextLogIn.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The Webdriver url from the parent class is not passing to the child class. Is their any Issues with my code. When I run the parent class with main method it navigate the browser  to the url but when I call from the child class it not giving the same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class member driver is not instantiated, in the method logInCreated() in the parent class you are using another object reference ( not the class member ).

in the LoginPage add a no arg constructor in wich you instntialize driver

```
public LoginPage(){ driver = new ChromeDriver(); }
```

and in the method LogInCredit() delete the line `WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: @MohamedYousuf If it works you can upvote the answer or mark it as correct. Or both.